# Postfix possible SMTP attack and blacklist

Tags: email, ubuntu, smtp, plesk, postfix-mta

I have plesk 12.5.30 on my server which is often blacklisted on Symantec Mail Security reputation.
The ip is new (I have purchased the server on 13.02.2017).

Also my ip is blacklisted on BACKSCATTERER.

Seeing the log of postfix I have a lot of entries like

```
Mar 22 14:51:43 server postfix/smtpd[14204]: connect from 75-143-80-240.dhcp.aubn.al.charter.com[75.143.80.240]
Mar 22 14:51:45 server postfix/smtpd[14204]: lost connection after EHLO from 75-143-80-240.dhcp.aubn.al.charter.com[75.143.80.240]
Mar 22 14:51:45 server postfix/smtpd[14204]: disconnect from 75-143-80-240.dhcp.aubn.al.charter.com[75.143.80.240]
Mar 22 14:51:50 server postfix/smtpd[14204]: connect from 128.128.72.76.cable.dhcp.goeaston.net[76.72.128.128]
Mar 22 14:51:51 server postfix/smtpd[14204]: lost connection after EHLO from 128.128.72.76.cable.dhcp.goeaston.net[76.72.128.128]
Mar 22 14:51:51 server postfix/smtpd[14204]: disconnect from 128.128.72.76.cable.dhcp.goeaston.net[76.72.128.128]
Mar 22 14:52:19 server postfix/smtpd[14204]: connect from mail.dedeckeraccountants.be[91.183.46.186]
Mar 22 14:52:19 server postfix/smtpd[14204]: disconnect from mail.dedeckeraccountants.be[91.183.46.186]
```

I have

1. Changed the smtp port to a non standard one (9456)
2. Installed firewall and fail2ban on plesk and setted [as in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRfNf.png)
3. Setted mail settings of plesk [as in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVyhl.png)
4. Installed a spamassasin

I have noticed also that some days ago i have lines in log like these

```
Mar 19 06:47:00 server postfix/smtp[13517]: CCC1C510023D: to=<229e7dc3183452c7d3290d1ba28f073e@www.lablue.de>, relay=none, delay=235637, delays=235636/0.05/0.09/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to www.lablue.de[217.22.195.26]:25: Connection refused)
Mar 19 06:47:00 server postfix/smtp[13503]: 7EDD55100138: to=<Weber226@brockel.kirche-rotenburg.de>, relay=kirche-rotenburg-verden.de[136.243.213.122]:25, delay=239980, delays=239979/0.01/0.35/0.1, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host kirche-rotenburg-verden.de[136.243.213.122] said: 451 Temporary local problem - please try later (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Mar 19 06:47:00 server postfix/smtp[13504]: 97B055100233: to=<office@angerlehner.at>, relay=none, delay=222922, delays=222922/0.01/0.64/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=angerlehner.at type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Mar 19 06:47:00 server postfix/smtp[13509]: 1E15F510019B: host mx1.leventboru.com.tr[89.19.1.69] said: 450 4.7.1 Recipient address rejected: Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable or not local (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

And i noticed a very long mail queue in plesk settings (i have deleted all mail in queue)

Any advice to block this attack??

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** I want to share my plesk-postfix settings

```
[plesk-postfix]
enabled = true
filter = postfix-sasl
action = iptables-multiport[name="plesk-postfix", port="http,https,smtp,submission,pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps,sieve", protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/maillog
maxretry = 2
```

There is somenthing can i improve here?

Comment: Your firewall could be stopping connections to your SMTP server

Comment: Can u tell me how can i do this block uising plesk?

Comment: The SMTP server on Plesk works correctly after Plesk is installed. You dont have to change the port. You can try to reinstall Plesk and then install the SMTP server with default settings. Postfix has built in features for preventing spams and open relays.

Comment: I can't reinitialize my server so install plesk from scratch. Now i have setted fail2ban with this code

failregex = lost connection after (AUTH|UNKNOWN|EHLO) from (.*)\[<HOST>\]
   connect from unknown\[<HOST>\]
   disconnect from unknown\[<HOST>\]
   connect from (.*)\[<HOST>\]
   disconnect from (.*)\[<HOST>\]
   .*warning.*hostname.*does not resolve to address <HOST>.*Name or service not known.*

Ips are blocked but...how can i definitely avoid this? Today i'm on symantec blacklist again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider to use a Fail2Ban - filter with the following regex - expressions:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)slost connection after (AUTH|UNKNOWN|EHLO) from [^\[]*\[<HOST>\]\s*$
```

If you need further Fail2Ban regex - expressions, pls. consider to ADD the corresponding log - file entries, because some general standart ones may not suit your needs or/and your qmail/postfix/imap-courier/dovecot version, installed on your server. ;-)

**Edit:**
In order to be more precise, I now add the **full** suggestion, incl. the regex, that @MattiaDiGiuseppe already used in his comments - it's just a bit better formatted this way.

```
[Definition]

_daemon = postfix(-\w+)?/(?:submission/|smtps/)?smtp[ds]

failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)swarning: (.*?)does not resolve to address <HOST>: Name or service not known$
        ^%(__prefix_line)swarning: [-._\w]+\[<HOST>\]: SASL ((?i)LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5) authentication failed(:[ A-Za-z0-9+/:]*={0,2})?\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 554 5\.7\.1 .* Relay access denied.*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sSSL_accept error from \S+\s*\[<HOST>\]: lost connection$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sSSL_accept error from \S+\s*\[<HOST>\]: -1$
        ^%(__prefix_line)slost connection after (AUTH|UNKNOWN|EHLO) from [^\[]*\[<HOST>\]\s*$

ignoreregex = authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server$
```

Pls. consider to have a look at all **standart filters** ( for Fail2Ban 0.10 AND older versions), by visiting:

=> https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/tree/0.10/config/filter.d

If you desire to view the standarts for older versions, just click on the "Branch: 0.10" dropdpwn - button, pls.

Comment: I have added this other filters. Read in my previous comment. I have to only add the filter you have suggested? Thanks

Comment: The expression I suggested is just a bit more precise - you could consider to replace it with yours.

Additional regex expression are always possible - just see examples in other ( standart ) filters, which you have in the folder "/etc/fail2ban/filter.d". ;-)

Comment: Ok now i have

[Definition]
_daemon = postfix/(submission/)?smtp(d|s)
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)slost connection after (AUTH|UNKNOWN|EHLO) from [^\[]*\[<HOST>\]\s*$
ignoreregex = authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server$

It's ok?

Comment: Thanks @UFHH01! now i have added some infos about settings of jail. Now i have added definition as your suggestion.
Can u advice me about jail's settings if they are correct and how can i improve these? Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't set "maxretry" to "2". Leave it at the standart = 5 . Just keep in mind, that people might TYPE username and password, instead of storing it, which could always lead to some mistakes. Users will get annoyed very fast, if you set this too low and they could experience issues, because of temporary Fail2Bans, caused by a low number of possible retries,

Comment: In addition, you could add "findtime = 43200" and "bantime = 86400" to your jail configuration and consider as well to use the RECIDIVE JAIL ( pls. see "jail.conf" !! ), which will ban returning users. ;-)